# How to match only items preceded by a-z, A-Z, space, or the start of a line when searching with grep?

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I need to display all lines in `file.txt` containing the character "鱼", but only those where "鱼" is immediately preceded by `a-z`, `A-Z`, a space, or a line break.

I tried using `grep`, like this:

```
grep "[a-zA-Z\s\n]鱼" file.txt
```

The regular expression `[a-zA-Z\s\n]` does not appear to work. How can I search for this character, when appearing after `a-z`, `A-Z`, a space, or a line break?

Comment: while `\n` is a linebreak, it's also usually ignored unless you force multiline regex interpretation, `^[a-zA-Z\s]鱼` might be what you're looking for. Also don't know how well grep deals with unicode, but you might actually be far better off with something like Sublime Text 2 or 3, which you can tell to open an entire directory, and then do a search-on-content in with ctrl/cmd-shift-f (depending on windows/*n*x vs. osx)

Comment: I thought if `^` is outside of `[]` it is no longer an "or" item, but it means there is `^` + one of the characters inside `[]` + "鱼".

Comment: Also, `^` placed inside `[]` seems to mean "don't include those items", so I am confused how to possibly, but not necessarily match the start of the line.

Comment: `^` at the start of a patterns means "the start of a line", with `$` meaning "the end of a line". `^[a-z]` is "the start of a line followed by any in the class a-z" for instance.

Comment: @Village: You use alternation (`|`) but you need to specify EREs by using the `-E` option or `egrep`. So `(^|[abc])%` is an ERE which matches a `%` at the beginning of the line *or* after one of `a`, `b` or `c`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to match a space with grep, use a space:

```
grep "[a-zA-Z ]鱼" file.txt
```

If you want to match any whitespace, you can use the Posix standard character class:

```
grep "[a-zA-Z[:space:]]鱼" file.txt
```

("Any whitespace" is space, newline, carriage return, form feed, tab and vertical tab. If you just want to match space and tab, you can use `[:blank:]`.)

You might also want to use a standard class for letters. Unless you are in the Posix or "C" locale, the meanings of character ranges like `A-Z` are unpredictable.

```
grep "[[:alpha:][:space:]]鱼" file.txt
```

`grep` works line by line, so it will never see a newline. But using an "extended" pattern, you can also match at the beginning of the line:

```
egrep "(^|[[:alpha:][:space:]])鱼" file.txt
```

(You can use `grep -E` instead of `egrep` if you prefer. But you need one or the other for the above regular expression to work.)

Comment: If `[[:alpha:][:space:]]` the same as `[:alpha:]|[:space:]`?

Comment: It's a little inaccurate to use `[:space:]`. Better use `[:blank:]` which is same as `<space>\t`. Technically it doesn't give a difference compared to my answer.

Comment: @Village: `[:alpha:]` (and similar) can only be used inside `[...]`. So `[:alpha:]|[:space:]` is not interpreted as "a letter or whitespace"; rather it is interpreted as `[:ahlp]|[:aceps]` which is the same as `[:acehlps]`, which is certainly not what you wanted. `[[:alpha:][:space:]]` is the same as `[[:alpha:]]|[[:space:]]`. Syntactically, `[:alpha:]` is just like `a-zA-Z`, which also must appear in brackets, but it is more accurate; `a-zA-Z` only works as expected in the "C" locale.

Answer (score 1):

Grep does not support this by default

```
$ man grep | grep '\\s'
```

But awk does

```
$ man awk | grep '\\s'
       \s         Matches any whitespace character.
```

So perhaps use

```
awk '/[a-zA-Z\s\n]鱼/' file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `awk`:

```
awk '/[A-Za-z \t]鱼/ || (NR > 1 && /^鱼/)' file
```

Which would print line if `鱼` is after `[A-Za-z \t]` or if it's not on the first line and it's in the beginning of the line: `NR > 1 && /^鱼/`.

If you just really want that it's on the beginning or is followed by `[A-Za-z \t]`, you can simply do this:

```
awk '/(^|[A-Za-z \t])鱼/' file
```

Or

```
grep -E '/(^|[A-Za-z \t])鱼/' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
^[a-zA-Z \n]{1,}鱼
```

`{1,}` will make u assure that `鱼` got at least 1 of these element before

what is more i suggest to use `awk` in this particular case